# Why do I get "command not found" when the binary file exists?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, libraries

Here's my problem. I have just compiled a linux build of `tests` in my VirtualBox VM. When I run it, I get:

```
bash: ./tests: No such file or directory
```

I did some research, and found it could permissions, missing libraries or different architecture. So I checked those:

- `ls -al tests`:

  ```
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 me me 9948598 2011-02-21 01:54 tests
  ```
- `file tests`

  ```
  tests: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped
  ```
- `uname -a`

  ```
  Linux DevBox 2.6.35-25-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 21 17:40:44 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- `ldd tests`:

  ```
  linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7db90000)
  libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f10ef14c000)
  libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f10eee46000)
  libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f10eec2d000) 
  libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f10ee9aa000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f10ee627000)
  /lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f10ef384000)
  libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f10ee410000)
  ```

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562071/how-can-i-find-which-elf-dependency-is-not-fulfill

Comment: That seemed promising, but I think my ELF interpreter is OK: `/lib/ld64.so.1 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f10ef384000)` and `readelf -l` says:  `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld64.so.1]`

Comment: So for some reason I was missing a link: `sudo ln -s /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib/ld64.so.1` made it work. Anybody know why that is? I'm accepting this cause it was the closest and most useful.

Comment: @nullspace: It's normal that `/lib/ld64.so.1` doesn't exist.  That `ld` default predates modern multi-arch FS layout, so `gcc` always passes `--dynamic-linker=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` to `ld`

Answer (score 0):

Is the file name really "tests" or does it only appear to be like that?

Try renaming the file, does it work? Without pressing TAB?

Perhaps you put in the name a not showing CTRL character somehow doing a copy&paste or pressing some key combination?

Does

```
stat tests
```

work if you write tests without pressing TAB?

Comment: This all worked fine.